# How to spawn multiple enemies?

Tags: java

I can store it in an array, ok, but after how can i paint it? Because if i do 
enemy = new Enemy();
enemy2 = new Enemy();
 i create two istances of the object, but afer how can i paint it?
I use:
g2d.drawImage(Enemy.getImage(), Enemy.getX(), Enemy.getY(), this);
But obviously it use the class, not the variable.
Images will not be overlyed because coordinates are random.
Excuse me my terrible english.

Comment: I wonder how you ever managed to paint a single enemy.

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing Enemy.getX() and not enemy.getX() and enemy2.getX(), why call static methods instead of instance methods?

Comment: Might just be a typo.

Comment: @Mario Maybe, but then they say "obviously it use the class, not the variable" so I doubt that. I think variable "means" instance.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you'll need some kind of container or collection to hold all entities. Then create some spawn or factory function to actually add them.

When drawing (or updating) your game entities, you'll just iterate through this list and modify them accordingly.

Here's some pseudo-code example:

```
List<Entity> entities;

function spawnEnemy(position pos) {
    entities.push(new Enemy(pos));
}

function updateEntities(time delta) {
    foreach(Entity entity : entities) {
        entity.update(delta);
    }
}

function drawEntities() {
    foreach(Entity entity : entities) {
        screen.draw(entity);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think their problem is that they are using a static method and not an instance method.